# ORDER BY discrete values of text column on [My]SQL[ite]

Tags: mysql, sqlite, sorting, sql-order-by

I would like to sort the rows in a table based on an arbitrary ordering of a limited set of values of a text (or enum) column. For instance, if column "Classes" can have the values A, B, C, D, I would like to be able to sort rows by A > C > B > D or by some other combination, and not just alphabetically or by the native order of the enum. Is that even possible?

Ideally, I would like a solution that works on SQLite, but a MySQL one would also be useful. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If mySQL and sqlite sllow the use of CASE in ORDER BY clauses (MSSQL does and I see no reason why other systems won't), you could use something like:

```
ORDER BY CASE
         WHEN classes ='A' THEN 1
         WHEN classes ='C' THEN 2
         WHEN classes ='B' THEN 3
         WHEN classes ='D' THEN 4
         ELSE 5
         END CASE
```

If the column can contain more than one of the options in any particular order you could also do:

```
ORDER BY CASE
         WHEN classes LIKE '%A%' THEN 1
         WHEN classes LIKE '%C%' THEN 2
         WHEN classes LIKE '%B%' THEN 3
         WHEN classes LIKE '%D%' THEN 4
         ELSE 5
         END CASE
```

though overloading a field like that is not a normal form and is generally not recommended.

Comment: While not as elegant as the FIELD or FIND_IN_SET MySQL functions, this actually works on SQLite (without the final CASE). Thank you!

Comment: I have also found out that the form: 
"ORDER BY CASE classes WHEN 'A' THEN 1 WHEN 'B' THEN 2..." also works, looks a bit better and might be slightly more efficient.

Comment: Aye, the final CASE is not used in MSSQL either, but if I remember rightly (it is a while since I've used mySQL for my own code) it is required by mySQL.

Comment: Yes, the CASE <something> WHEN <constant> form is a valid shorthand when you don't need any comparisons other than "is equal".

Answer (score 3):

```
ORDER BY field(column, 'A', 'C', 'B', 'D')
```

[FIELD function in MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variant - add a new (temporary?) table such as

```
class | rank
A     | 1
B     | 2
C     | 3
D     | 4
```

Then you can join the table by the `class` column and order by the `rank`.